# Swig deferencing python temporaries in typemap

Tags: python, c, swig

I want to pass a Python `datetime` object to the function `printme` below, seamlessly.

```
struct DateTime {
    uint64_t epochns;
};
void printme(DateTime dt);
```

So far I was able to create this SWIG typemap to convert from `datetime` to `DateTime`

```
%typemap(in)  DateTime
{
    PyObject* str = PyString_FromString( "timestamp" );
    PyObject* obj = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs( $input, str, nullptr );
    $1.epochns = PyLong_AsLong( obj );
}
```

My question is: am I leaking the variables `str` and `obj`?  Do I need to dereference them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`PyString_FromString`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#c.PyString_FromString) and [`PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#c.PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs) are documented to return a new reference, so both `str` and `obj` must be released via [`Py_DECREF`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html#c.Py_DECREF) or [`Py_XDECREF`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html#c.Py_XDECREF) or you will leak two references.